# Bash - Using the AT command without a file

Tags: linux, shell, at-job

It might sound odd, but I need to run the **AT** command and schedule a command but I don't want to make a file and send it to AT with the **-f** option. Is it somehow possible to write the whole thing in one single line. Suppose I want to run the **"gnome-terminal"** at the time 13:10.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`at` reads from standard input by default, i.e. if `-f` is not used. You can pass multiple lines in several ways, e.g. using here documents:

```
at << EOF
first line
second line
EOF
```

Or within a single line (specific to bash):

```
at <<< $'first line\nsecond line'
```